# Problems when using chemscheme/chemstyle with Palatino and T1 encoding

Tags: font-encodings, chemstyle

Automatic generation of compound numbers by `chemscheme` (part of `chemstyle`) works:

- In Latin Modern (`lmodern`) with **T1** *or* **OT1** encoding
- In Palatino (`mathpazo`) with **OT1** encoding, but *not* with T1 encoding - instead, the numbers simply vanish (see example below).

This is presumably down to Palatino's use of bitmap fonts, when switched to T1. I'd like to find a way to carry on using Palatino (or similar), but be able to use the automatic compound numbering features of `chemstyle` (or rather the underlying `chemcompounds`)

---

**Fully working version**

Taking, as my MWE, a version of the example document from the `chemstyle` documentation which works as it's supposed to:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage[journal=rsc]{chemstyle}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\begin{scheme}[ht]
\includegraphics{chemscheme}
\caption{A scheme with temporary compound numbers.}
\end{scheme}

\begin{scheme}[ht]
\schemeref{IMesHCl}
\schemeref{IMes}
\includegraphics{chemscheme}
\caption{A scheme with automated compound numbers.}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

The above uses the eps file from the `chemstyle` manual, *i.e.* chemscheme.eps . As best I can tell, that eps doesn't seem to be available as-is in the `chemstyle` documentation – rather, there's a chemscheme.cdx (a ChemDrawfile) that (for those with ChemDraw) can be saved as eps. **Edit**: Alternatively, I've uploaded a copy at http://dur.ac.uk/o.w.j.burnham/stackexchange/chemscheme.eps.

When run, with shell-escape enabled, via

```
pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex
```

I get, as expected,

[image: example of compiled PDF using chemscheme code, showing two schemes: one with temporary compound numbers, and one with these replace by automatically-generated numbers]

*i.e.* in the second scheme, the placeholders (TMP1 and TMP2) from the eps have been replaced by automatically-generated numbers.

---

**The error**

However, if I disable Latin Modern, *i.e.* if the document reads

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage[journal=rsc]{chemstyle}
%\usepackage{lmodern}    %Latin Modern disabled. Now using Computer Modern.

\begin{document}

\begin{scheme}[ht]
\includegraphics{chemscheme}
\caption{A scheme with temporary compound numbers.}
\end{scheme}

\begin{scheme}[ht]
\schemeref{IMesHCl}
\schemeref{IMes}
\includegraphics{chemscheme}
\caption{A scheme with automated compound numbers.}
\end{scheme}

\end{document}
```

and, therefore, the document compiles using the default font (Computer Modern), the automated compounds numbers vanish. The problem also occurs if I replace Latin Modern with Palatino, *i.e.* if I replace `lmodern` with `mathpazo`. In either case I get something like this, where the auto-generated numbers are missing:

[image: example of compiled PDF using chemscheme when using Palatino font. The automatically-generated numbers are no longer shown]

Happily (?) this can be fixed – using Computer Modern or Palatino – by removing `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, so as to return to the default (OT1) font-encoding:

[image: example of compiled PDF using chemscheme when using Palatino font with OT1 encoding. The automatically-generated numbers have returned]

So, in summary, as best I can tell, automatic generation of compound numbers works:

- In Latin Modern with **T1** *or* **OT1** encoding
- In Computer Modern with **OT1** encoding (but *not* with T1 encoding)
- In Palatino with **OT1** encoding (but *not* with T1 encoding)

As best I understand it, this correlates with Computer Modern and Palatino's use of bitmap fonts when switched to T1 encoding. Intuitively it makes some sense to me that the eps – being a vector format – works with vector fonts but not with bitmaps, and so the use of bitmap fonts here could lead to problems.

---

Possible solutions that have occurred to me:

1. **Use Latin Modern** – I would prefer not to, as I like Palatino
2. **Use a Palatino-like font that has a vector form in T1** – however, I don't
   know of any such font!
3. **Use Palatino except in the context of compound numbering** – however, I don't know how I'd go about doing this

If anyone has any other ideas for possible fixes but without knowing how they would implement them, I'll happily make edits and add any such suggestions to this list, in case someone else can them work out how to implement them.

Comment: Since I don't have chemdraw, I can't test it myself, but maybe give package `kpfonts` a shot, it looks similar to `mathpazo` but is more recent.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Thanks, that looks like it might be a working solution. If it works for me I'll let you know and you should post it as an answer.

Additionally, I've edited the post to include a link to the eps file, so that people without ChemDraw can test.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Looks like `kpfonts` doesn't work for me, but not for any reasons to do with this particular example -- I just can't get it working with any document . The similar `pxfonts` seems like it might do the job, but lacks some of the features (like old style figures) that `kpfonts` and `mathpazo` have.

Comment: Your example with the eps works fine for me in a current miktex and in a current texlive. Can you show the log-file of the last pdflatex run?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's occurred to me that my post might not have been very clear. For avoidance of doubt I've now edited it, but just in case: the full MWE at the start (i.e. using Latin Modern) works perfectly well. The issue (in case that was unclear) is if I use Computer Modern (or Palatino) -- I've edited so that there's now a full MWE for the erroneous version now.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer However, in case I had been perfectly clear, and the meant-to-be-broken version is in fact working fine for you, I've put onto pastebin the log files for the working version ( https://pastebin.com/jqVjwUUx ) and the not-working version ( https://pastebin.com/rUhpL1VW ). I didn't want to cut out something useful so I've put them there in full -- I trust others to know better what's relevant!

Comment: I did understand the part about the various font variants. All worked for me. You have a pk-font in your log (ecrm1000.pk). Install the cm-super package (large package, can take some time, you will perhaps have to call updmap after the installation) and then try again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. Was (as ever) just worried that I'd been unclear.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer After installing `cm-super` and running `updmap`, it now works perfectly for both Computer Modern and Palatino. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer`kpfonts`worked perfectly for me once I'd updated the filename database (and before I'd installed cm-super to get mathpazo etc. working. So thanks for that!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Let me know if you want to post that as an answer. Otherwise, I'm happy to type it up and Community Wiki it.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Let me know if you want to post that as an answer. Otherwise, I'm happy to type it up and Community Wiki it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bitmap (pk-)font in your log (`ecrm1000.pk`) which is the source of the problem.

Install the cm-super package (large package, can take some time and in miktex you will perhaps have to call `updmap` after the installation to activate the map-file) and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Give package `kpfonts` a shot, it looks similar to `mathpazo` but is more recent. (Credit to  [Michael Palmer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394678/problems-when-using-chemscheme-chemstyle-with-palatino-and-t1-encoding#comment981351_394678))